# Formatting Date in PHP using msaccess with ODBC

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I'm converting my ASP CLASSIC site to PHP. The site uses MS Access as database and using ODBC to connect with Databse. i'm stuck with the date formatting.

**I used to Format Dates in asp as follows:**

```
select U_ID, Trans_Code, Format(Due_Date, 'dd-mmm-yyyy') AS Due_Date
```

Used the same Format function in PHP but it returns error.

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] Circular reference caused by alias 'Due_Date' in query
>   definition's SELECT list., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in
>   C:\wamp\www\files.php on line 28

Then i changed the alias to `DDATE` the error disappears and data returns without Formatting.

I have also tried the non-sql way, but its also returns error.

**Here's the date_format function i used.**

```
echo "<td>". Date_Format($DueDate,"d.m.y") ."</td>\n";
```

**Returns this error:**

> Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime,

**Also tried this:**

```
echo "<td>". Date_Format(DateTime($DueDate,"d.m.y")) ."</td>\n";
```

Any help would be much appreciated . . . :)

Comment: What error message do you get? The first PHP method should work if `$DueDate` is a date object.

Comment: `Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime,` `$DueDate` holds the record from SQL in this format `2013-08-12 00:00:00`

Comment: Assign the result from the query to a datetime object first, and then format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed the errors :)

Thanks to S. Ahn for suggesting this:

`Assign the result from the query to a datetime object first, and then format it`

**Create the datetime object first**

```
$DueDate=date_create(odbc_result($rs,"ddate"));
```

**And then formatted it.**

```
echo "<td>". date_format($DueDate,"j-F-Y") ."</td>\n";
```